# How can I sort an array that is already sorted by a secondary criteria?

Tags: arrays, sorting, pseudocode

Suppose I have an array of objects. Each object contains and integer and a string.

These objects have been sorted so that they are in alphabetical order, and no two objects contain the same string.

I want to sort the array so that they are in order from lowest to highest integer, and for objects with the same integer I want to sort tem in alphabetical order

For example I start with:

```
[1 "ab"],[2 "bc"],[1 "cd"],[3 "de"],[2 "ef"]
```

and it should be sorted to:

```
[1 "ab"],[1 "cd"],[2 "bc"],[2 "ef"],[3 "de"]
```

Is there a faster way than just sorting with language built in comparator sort functions? (where I provide a comparison function)

Comment: Any [stable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm#Stability) sorting algorithm will do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There could be, but
I think comparison function is much better than anything

```
bool comp(obj a, obj b)
{
    if(a.num==b.num)return a.str < b.str;
    return a.num<b.num;
}
```

call to comp function    `sort(arr, arr+size, comp)`